# C# Reference Counting

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, reference

I am looking for a good pattern to implement ref counting in C#. I have a

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> ObjList;
```

What I want to do is hand out references to `MyObject` instances if they exist and create new ones if they don't.  Multiple places in my code may make a reference to a `MyObject` instance but when all are freed up I would like to remove it from my dictionary.  I have looked into `WeakReference` but Im not sure if it is applicable here??

Edit 1.)
Specifics I am using an [OPC](http://www.opcdatahub.com/WhatIsOPC.html) Server so whenever I reference an Item I would like to use the dictionary to lookup existing references to the item.  When I dont need the item anymore I want to unsubscribe from the item.  It isnt easy to know when or how many place in my code are currently using the item.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to do...

Comment: What I am doing is using an OPC server so when a object has no references I want to unsubscribe from it.  I am under the impression that my dictionary will always have a reference so it will never be disposed

Comment: `WeakReference` would work, but if you can afford to dispose of instances explicitly, I would just go with that.

Comment: It is important to note that `MyObject` must correctly implement `IDisposable` **with a class destructor that calls `.Dispose()`** otherwise the `WeakReference` to `MyObject` will not be disposed.

Answer (score 6):

What I have done in these scenarios is create a dictionary of [`WeakReferences`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx).  What a `WeakReference` does is allow your dictionary to refer to an instance of `MyObject` without keeping that instance in memory.  Therefore, once all the other references to that object have been freed, an entry for the item will still exist in the dictionary.  However, that entry will refer to a `WeakReference` where `IsAlive` is `false` and the `Target` is `null`.  If you want, you can occasionally clean up the dictionary by removing all the entries where the `WeakReference` is not alive.

Answer (score 4):

This is the kind of thing you need:

```
public class WeakReferences<T>
{
    private Func<string, T> _factory;

    public WeakReferences(Func<string, T> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, WeakReference> _references =
        new Dictionary<string, WeakReference>();

    public T this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
            T target = default(T);
            if (_references.ContainsKey(index))
            {
                var wr = _references[index];
                target = (T)wr.Target;
                if (wr.IsAlive)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Reused: " + index);
                    return target;
                }
            }
            target = _factory(index);
            _references[index] = new WeakReference(target);
            return target;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
    Func<string, object> f = k =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Created: " + k);
        return new object();
    };

    var wrs = new WeakReferences<object>(f);

    var a = wrs["a"];
    var b = wrs["b"];
    a = wrs["a"];
    b = wrs["b"];
    a = null;
    GC.Collect();
    a = wrs["a"];
    b = wrs["b"];
```

The output I get running this is:

```
Created: a
Created: b
Reused: a
Reused: b
Created: a
Reused: b
```

Comment: The tricky part is how would you perform code the cleanup code. In your example above how would you get.    Deleted: a. I need to place code to tell the Opc server I'm done

Comment: @MDK - You don't need to tell this to clean-up at all. It's all weak references - once you no longer have any references elsewhere in your code all of this will be cleaned up by the GC.

Comment: @MDK - If the objects you are adding need to be disposed of then it would be trivial to remove the need for the `Func<string, T> factory` and allow external assignment of the instances so that you can manage disposal yourself.

Comment: So I guess your saying there is no automatic way to tell when an object is dereferenced.  I didnt want to rely on other users of my code to explicitly dispose of objects.

Comment: @MDK - You **must** explicitly dispose of your objects. The garbage collector **does not** do it automatically. So it doesn't help you to be able to check if the object is referenced or not. Nonetheless you can check the `IsAlive` property of a `WeakReference` to see if it has been garbage collected or not. But again, this **does not** tell you if it has been disposed or not. I think you might need to let us know how you need to manage the lifetime of your objects so that we can advise you on the best way to go.

Comment: @MDK - Dispose of MyObjects, not in your dictionary, but in MyObject.Dispose: you have MyObject implement IDisposable. *That* is where you put any logic you need. Have MyObject contain a pointer back to the dictionary, and MyObject.Dispose call a method of the dictionary via that pointer. That dictionary method can then tell OPC server, and remove the MyObject WeakReference.